# Bash script to convert windows path to linux path

Tags: linux, windows, bash, sed, path

I'm new to shell scripting and trying to accomplish following, converting a windows path to a linux path and navigating to that location:

Input: `cdwin "J:\abc\def"`
Action: `cd /usr/abc/def/`

So, I'm changing the following:

```
"J:" -> "/usr"
```

and

```
"\" -> "/"
```

This is my try, but it doesn't work. It just returns a blank if i echo it:

```
function cdwin(){
    line="/usrfem/Projects$1/" | sed 's/\\/\//g' | sed 's/J://'
    cd $line
}
```

Comment: 2 consecutive sed  seaprate by a pipe could often be done in 1 sed separate by a ";" ex: echo "/usrfem/Projects$1/" | sed 's|\\|/|g;s/J://' in yours case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to catch the variable and then process it.

For example this would make it:

```
function cdwin(){
    echo "I receive the variable --> $1"
    line=$(sed -e 's#^J:##' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "$1")
    cd "$line"
}
```

And then you call it with

```
cdwin "J:\abc\def"
```

#### Explanation

The command

```
line=$(sed -e 's#^J:##' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "$1")
```

is equivalent to

```
line=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's#^J:##' -e 's#\\#/#g')
```

and replaces every `\` with `/`, saving the result into the var `line`. Note it uses another delimiter, `#`, to make it more readable. It also removes the leading `J:`.

Comment: Change the replacement to this `line=$(sed -e 's#^\(.\):#/mnt/\L\1#' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "$1")` to make it work with WSL/Ubuntu on windows 10 for any drive and path

Comment: When I run this code I get the error `-bash: cd: ~/work/projects: No such file or directory`, but if I manually run `cd ~/work/projects` from the command line, it works. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How to use the cdwin() ? Do I place it in .profile ? or do I need to create a file with the same name and do chmod +x and put the  file in my PATH?

Answer (score 3):

sed allows alternative delimiters so better to not to use `/`.

Try this sed command:

```
sed -e 's~\\~/~g' -e 's~J:~/usr~' <<< "$line"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to use sed (although there's nothing wrong with using sed). 
This works for me using bash string substitution:

```
function cdwin() {
  line=${1/J://usr}
  line=${line//\\//}
  cd "$line"
}
```

`cdwin 'J:\abc\def'`

Substitution works as follows (simplification):

```
${var/find/replace}
```

and double slash means replace all:

```
${var//findall/replace}
```

In argument `1`, replace the first instance of `J:` with `/usr`:

```
${1/J://usr}
```

In variable `line` replace all (`//`) backslashes (escaped, `\\`)  with (`/`) forwardslash (`/`):

```
${line//\\//}
```

echo the output of any of those to see how they work

Answer (score 0):

My code is inspired by the top post but modified to work with any drive on windows 10 while running on native ubuntu (aka WSL).

You can comment out the debugging lines if you just want the function.

You can comment out the `cd` line if you just want output path

```
function cdwin() {
    # Converts Windows paths to WSL/Ubuntu paths, prefixing /mnt/driveletter and preserving case of the rest of the arguments,
    # replacing backslashed with forwardslashes
    # example: 
    # Input -> "J:\Share"
    # Output -> "/mnt/j/Share"
    echo "Input --> $1" #for debugging
    line=$(sed -e 's#^\(.\):#/mnt/\L\1#' -e 's#\\#/#g' <<< "$1")
    #Group the first character at the beginning of the string. e.g. "J:\Share", select "J" by using () but match only if it has colon as the second character
    #replace J: with /mnt/j
    #\L = lowercase , \1 = first group (of single letter)
    # 2nd part of expression
    #replaces every \ with /, saving the result into the var line. 
    #Note it uses another delimiter, #, to make it more readable.
    echo "Output --> $line" #for debugging
    cd "$line" #change to that directory
}
```