# How to convert Windows path to UNIX path

Tags: github-actions

I'm writing a GitHub Actions workflow that will run on Linux, Windows, and macOS. To avoid redundancy, I want to use the same steps on all platforms as far as possible. This includes UNIX commands like `curl` and `tar` that aren't available in PowerShell, the default shell on Windows. So I'm planning to explicitly set the shell to `bash` on all platforms.

Which brings up the problem: `bash` expects UNIX paths in commands, but from the documentation, it seems that all environment variables contain platform-specific paths. So on Windows, all environment variables will contain Windows paths. How can I convert them to UNIX paths for use in `bash`?

**Edit:** Clarifications:

- The paths I'm talking about are [environment variables set by GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) such as `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`.
- For each step of a job, GitHub Actions allows me to [explicitly specify the shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) to be used. So running `bash` on Windows in a one-liner in GitHub Actions and doesn't require any installation.
- This question is primarily about best practices in GibHub Actions, not about what is possible using bash scripts. If the only way to convert the path is to use a bash script, then @Yahampath's comment answers my question. But I was hoping the GitHub team had thought of a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can have curl and tar in Windows the same way you get bash: by installing them. Have you tried bash on Windows to see what happens?

Comment: There are a lot of nebulous details going on in this question, such as what paths you need to convert and how exactly you plan to run bash commands on Windows. There's no magic bullet answer for your question in its current form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bash script to convert windows path to linux path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999562/bash-script-to-convert-windows-path-to-linux-path)

Comment: Either PowerShell or bash can be used on all platforms (on GitHub Actions virtual machines), so if you don't feel good about bash, then use PowerShell.